# Replace or enhance default on-screen Keyboard

Tags: tablet, onboard, onscreen-keyboard

I am running Ubuntu 19.04 on a Surface Go. There is the default on-screen keyboard which looks exactly like the ones on phones.
But I need (at least sometimes) the extra keys like <kbd>Alt</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>, and Umlauts.

So I would like either too enhance the default layout or disable it and use Onboard. I couldn't find any useful hints.

Could anyone help me here?

Answer (score 0):

From the Ubuntu Documentation:

Press the flag ([image: Flag Image]) button to change your settings for Language or Input Sources.

If you are unable to do so, you can change the layout of the keyboard via following this [guide](https://linoxide.com/linux-how-to/configure-keyboard-ubuntu/).

To qoute from the article:

If you wish to configure the keyboard for the current session only, run

```
dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration
```

Then select the layout with the extra keys (like Alt, Ctrl and umlauts).

If you want to replace the On Screen Keyboard, use this [guide](https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/replace-gnome-onscreen-keyboard-florence-virtual-keyboard-linux/) to install florence keyboard to your system. It is extremely configurable.

Comment: With the Language selection I could not change the default on-screen keyboard layout. It still misses Umlauts and the CTRL key etc. But what it did it changed how the attached keyboard works :( Now my ALT key is not working anymore.

To be able to use Florence properly I need to disable the default on-screen keyboard which I couldn't do.

BTW I am using Ubuntu 19.04 on a Surface Go.